# .htaccess file modification

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file which arranges that all requests go through index.php.
Now i would like to make an exception for rss.php. to go straight throuh rss.php.
How do I do this?

This is how it looks like now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this before the last line.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rss\.php$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude any existing file with an additional [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I got slated yesterday for posting an answer that didn't answer the question. Sanders specifically asked to route all requests to index.php except for rss.php.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively do a rewrite that matches the file then skips the rest of the rewrite tests.

By putting the following line before your existing RewriteRule will redirect without going through index.php.

```
RewriteRule  ^/rss.php  /rss.php  [L]
```

I came across this page while hunting for a way to do this with my /robots.txt file.

[mod_rewrite with apache1.3](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)